# Move RecyclerView while scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which I would like to move vertically depending on how much user scrolled inside it. I've create custom RecyclerView.OnScrollListener to track the distance scrolled:

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView rView, int dx, int dy) {
  setY(dy)
}
```

Method setY changes coordinates of the RecyclerView like this:

```
recyclerView.setY(recyclerView.getY + dy)
```

The problem with this approach is that RecyclerView is "vibrating" while changing it's position. That means View is shaking while moving it. I think dy gets wrong while moving position of RecyclerView. How can I get rid of the vibration and move RecyclerView smoothly? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you add more details? If you are trying to implement nested scrolling, RecyclerView supports it since 22.2

Comment: @yigit, Thanks but I don't want to implement nested scrolling. I would like to move the whole RecyclerView.

Comment: I'm also want know answer. How I can resolve shiver ? when move.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that modifying recycler view position without the "vibration" can be achieved through the use of padding.

I've wrote a custom LayoutManager, in this case GridLayoutManager but can be any kind that does this for the vertical position by overriding `scrollVerticallyBy`:

Assign custom layout manager to your recyclerview:

```
CustomGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new CustomGridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Create custom layout manager:

```
private class CustomGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager{   
    CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        recyclerView.setPadding(recyclerView.getPaddingLeft(),
                recyclerView.getPaddingTop() - dy,
                recyclerView.getPaddingRight(),
                recyclerView.getPaddingBottom());

        return super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy,recycler,state);
    }

}
```

This is old, but I hope it helps someone.